# Is there a PHP based CMS that can Create,edit,add fields of JSON?

Tags: php, ajax, json, content-management-system, jsonp

I m a front end developer, with basic Understanding of PHP.
I m looking out for a PHP Based CMS that can edit/add/delete fields of a JSON file.

Features That i m looking out for 
1. Should be PHP based & Easy to Install (like WordPress).Reason I m looking out for a PHP Based CMS : PHP is very well known language and supported by most shared hosting companies.

2. All the users can remove/add new objects/Arrays(like adding products, services,client names/logos, testimonials), etc.

3.Some of the users will not be allowed to CHANGE/MODIFY the **structure of JSON**. The structure can only be modified via an Admin.

3.Can import an existing JSON and create the structure(not at all mandatory)

4.Reason I m not looking out for something like a flat file based CMS (like [Grav](http://getgrav.org/)) : I want the content to be in JSON format and not a part of CMS or website.

5. Should be Open-source and JSONP compatible. (not at all mandatory). 

 
 
6. Although it is self explanatory, but I will be calling the JSON via an Ajax call, so for performance reasons: it should allow multiple exports. for instance :
www.xyz.com/services/products.json 
www.xyz.com/services/services.json 
www.xyz.com/services/about.json 
www.xyz.com/services/testimonials.json 
 
www.xyz.com/services/clients.json 
 

7. just to clarify, I m not looking out for something as extensive as Wordpress. I m just looking out for a CMS that can modify JSON. Thats it. (obviously it should have a [WYSIWYG](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-wysiwyg/) editor to add and modify `<hml>` content)

**The main features are 1 and 2.**

Thanks.

Comment: what you're asking for is a REST server, and  database. it has nothing to do with a CMS .   such a thing can not be simple because you'd need to define the database-structure somewhere.

Comment: JSON structure can be defined via cms. Not sure what you mean by "database-structure". Sorry i m quite new to cms

Comment: start writing your own CMS

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/postlight/awesome-cms) list of cms systems.

Answer (score 0):

No currently there isn't exist any.

But it's a good idea to do but majority of CMS features that wordpress provide may be harder to even implement. As wordpress allows to integrate plugins with existing data.

Further if you want to develop by your self you can use couchbase for json storage which will be much more easy to develop and will allow to get the perfect system as per your requirement.

Comment: Not sure who -2 This. I have googled and failed. may be the person who -2ed this can have the CMS made lol. Bdw thanks Alpesh for an Answer.